# Не удаётся добавить PPA: «'Данный PPA не поддерживает bionic'»

Tags: linux, linux-mint, tor

Ошибка при установке tor-browser ([инструкция](https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/tor-browser))

```
$ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:webupd8team/tor-browser
```

Ошибка:

```
HTTP Error 404: Not Found
Не удаётся добавить PPA: «'Данный PPA не поддерживает bionic'».
```

Как установить браузер Tor в Linux Mint?

Comment: Скорее всего этот репозиторий устарел (максимум поддерживаются репозитории на основе Ubuntu 17.04 Zesty Zapus). Попробуйте установить по этой инструкции: https://itsecforu.ru/2019/02/11/установка-браузера-tor-на-linux-mint-19-ubuntu-18-04/

Answer (score 1):

В репозитории есть такой пакет:

```
torbrowser-launcher
```

Попробуй его поставить, этого будет достаточно.